# Put numbers in legend using pgf pie

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgf-pie

I would like to have the numbers that are inside the pie chart to be in the legend. How can I make that happen?

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pie[text=legend,style=drop shadow,radius=2]{51.3/Protestant, 23.9/Roman Catholic, 3.3/Other Christian, 1.7/Jewish, 0.7/Buddhist, 0.6/Muslim, 0.4/Hindu, 1.2/Other religions, 16.1/No religion }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

EDIT:

I also have another pie chart, where the text is quite long. How can I set the width of the text so that it wraps around before the page ends? Here is what it looks like:

[image]

I forgot that PGF-PIE was not on CTAN. Here is a link to the google source: http://code.google.com/p/pgf-pie/

Comment: `pgf-pie` isn't on CTAN, a link to where one can find it (http://code.google.com/p/pgf-pie/ I assume) would be nice.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Sorry about that! **EDIT** Link has been added to the post.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `pgf-pie` package is not as flexible as one wishes. Unfortunately, `etoolbox` refuses to patch, so we do it manually.

Open up (make a copy/backup) the `pgf-pie.sty` file and scroll to the end, there is a part enclosed in `\iflegend … \fi`. Replace the enclosed `scope` environment with:

```
  \begin{scope}[node distance=+0pt]
    \foreach \p/\t  [count=\i from 0] in {#2}
    {
      \pgfpie@findColor{\i}
      \node[below=of legendpos.south west, anchor=north west, every legend entry/.try, name=legendpos] {\t\ifpienumberinlegend\legendbeforenumber\p\legendafternumber\fi};
      \node[draw, fill=\thecolor, \style, at=(legendpos.base west), anchor=south east] {};
    }
  \end{scope}
```

Now you can use the `number in legend` style (which should come after `before number` and `after number`!).

For long legend entries, you can use the `every legend entry` style, say

```
every legend entry/.append style={text width=2cm}
```

The setup now allows this (the node distance is set to zero as the `inner ysep` creates, in my opinion, enough room between the entries.

You need the `positioning` library for the newer `below=of` syntax.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shadows}

\newif\ifpienumberinlegend
\pgfkeys{/number in legend/.code=
    \expandafter\let\expandafter\ifpienumberinlegend
    \csname if#1\endcsname
    \ifpienumberinlegend
    \let\legendbeforenumber\beforenumber
    \let\legendafternumber\afternumber
    \def\beforenumber##1\afternumber{}%
    \fi,
    /number in legend/.default=true
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every legend entry/.append style={text width=2cm}]
\pie[text=legend, style=drop shadow, radius=2, before number=\ (, after number=\,\%), number in legend]{51.3/Protestant, 23.9/Roman Catholic, 3.3/Other Christian, 1.7/Jewish, 0.7/Buddhist, 0.6/Muslim, 0.4/Hindu, 1.2/Other religions, 16.1/No religion }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Is there alternative to the label length? Because, you are right, there isn't much difference.

Comment: @gekkostate See the updated version.

Comment: This definitely deserves a bounty! This is awesome.

Comment: Can we remove the number somehow and just use label inside the pie?