# Latex: picture near text

Tags: tikz-pgf, description, pgf-pie

I need to have a pie char near a descption block like:
[image]

```
-----------------------------------
| Righe totali      |             |
| Completezza       |  pie chart  |
|                   |             |
-----------------------------------
```

at this moment my code is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{report}

\usepackage{pgf-pie} %grafici pie
\usepackage{tikz} %grafici pie
\pgfkeys{/number in legend/.code=
    \expandafter\let\expandafter\ifpienumberinlegend
    \csname if#1\endcsname
    \ifpienumberinlegend
    \let\legendbeforenumber\beforenumber
    \let\legendafternumber\afternumber
    \def\beforenumber##1\afternumber{}%
    \fi,
    /number in legend/.default=true
}


\begin{document}

\begin{description}
    \item[Righe totali] 1,699,382
    \item[Copletezza] 0.76698 (valore inventato) 
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \pie[color={black!10}, text=legend, sum=1, radius=0.5, number in legend]{0.76698/ Completezza}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

But I know it isn't correct. How can I do it?

Comment: welcome to TeX-SE!please, extend your code snipped to complete but small document with `\documentclas{...}` on beginning and `\end{document}` on the end.

Comment: How should the picture be positioned?

Comment: Reference for `number in legend`: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112140/put-numbers-in-legend-using-pgf-pie

Comment: If what you're asking is how to move the diagram up/down in relation to the line of text it's placed on, you want the `baseline` key, e.g. `\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=2mm]`

Comment: Where is `\pie` defined?  It's not in standard tikz.

Comment: Put the description in a `minipage` and the picture in another. `\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}\begin{description}...\end{description}\end{minipage}\begin{minipage{.45\linewidth}\begin{tikzpicture}...\end{tikzpicture}\end{minipage}`. Adjust widths as desired.

Comment: Looks like @cfr's comment  is what you're after.

Comment: thanks!
I solve using:

\begin{minipage}[c]{.5\textwidth}
 \begin{description}
  \item[Righe totali] 1,699,382
  \item[Copletezza] 0.76698 (valore inventato)
 \end{description}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[c]{.5\textwidth}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \pie[color={black!10}, text=legend, sum=1, radius=0.5, number in legend]{0.76698/ Completezza}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}

Comment: @cfr would you like to convert your comment into an answer?

Comment: @samcarter Done ;).

Comment: @Razzo Note that if you use `.5\textwidth` for both, you should make sure that any line ending between the two is commented as there is not room for a space there. Also, make sure that you use `\noindent` if there's a paragraph break before them. Otherwise, you'll get bad box warnings. (This is why I used only `.5` and `.45` of the available width, as the picture really didn't need half of the line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to align the list with the picture, keeping normal line-spacing within the list itself.

This can be done by putting the list in one `miniopage` and the picture in another. For example,

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{geometry}% for correct A4
\usepackage{pgf-pie,calc} %grafici pie
\pgfkeys{/number in legend/.code=
  \expandafter\let\expandafter\ifpienumberinlegend
  \csname if#1\endcsname
  \ifpienumberinlegend
  \let\legendbeforenumber\beforenumber
  \let\legendafternumber\afternumber
  \def\beforenumber##1\afternumber{}%
  \fi,
  /number in legend/.default=true
}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
  \begin{description}
    \item[Righe totali] 1,699,382
    \item[Copletezza] 0.76698 (valore inventato)
  \end{description}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.45\linewidth}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pie[color={black!10}, text=legend, sum=1, radius=0.5, number in legend]{0.76698/ Completezza}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image: pie to right of list]

I've used a total of 95% of the text block's width for the mini-pages, with a space between the two. Adjust as desired.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you are using `pgf-pie.sty`. You can put the number in the label your self by removing it from the chart and typing it directly in the label. To remove the number from the chart use a `\gobble` command (don't print argument) in `before number`. In the following example I have defined a command for it so you don't have to type the number twice. (This command only works if you have one input number. Otherwise you need to add the number by hand).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgf-pie}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand\gobble[1]{}
\newcommand\MyPie[2]{% Number, label
  \smash{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \pie[color={black!10}, text=legend, sum=1, radius=0.5,before number=\gobble,after number=,]{#1/ #2 #1}
    \end{tikzpicture}}}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{description}
\item[Righe totali] 1,699,382
\item[Copletezza] 0.76698 (valore inventato) \MyPie{0.76698}{Copletezza}
\end{description}  

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{report}


\usepackage{pgf-pie} %grafici pie
\usepackage{tikz} %grafici pie
\pgfkeys{/number in legend/.code=
    \expandafter\let\expandafter\ifpienumberinlegend
    \csname if#1\endcsname
    \ifpienumberinlegend
    \let\legendbeforenumber\beforenumber
    \let\legendafternumber\afternumber
    \def\beforenumber##1\afternumber{}%
    \fi,
    /number in legend/.default=true
}
 \usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[10]
\begin{description}
    \item[Righe totali] 1,699,382
    \item[Copletezza] 0.76698 (valore inventato)\hfill
    \raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]{\begin{tikzpicture}
        \pie[color={black!10}, text=legend, sum=1, radius=0.5, number in legend]{0.76698/ Completezza}
    \end{tikzpicture}}
\end{description}

\lipsum[11]

\end{document}
```

[image]