# Custom Pie Chart with plain tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pie

I drawed a custom pie chart with plain tikz using a combination of arcs and triangles. All fits well so far. One major remaining problem is that there are thin white lines appearing at the intersection of the triangles with the filled out arcs (see for example in piece 28.8%). Does anyone knows how to fix this? And if anyone has some suggestions as to how to automate the calculation of the angles in each of the following pieces I would appretiate some advice to that too.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

%Style Definitions
\tikzstyle{piece1} = [fill=black!5] 
\tikzstyle{piece2} = [fill=black!20]
\tikzstyle{piece3} = [fill=black!35]
\tikzstyle{piece4} = [fill=black!50]
\tikzstyle{piece5} = [fill=black!65]
\tikzstyle{line} = [line width=0.4pt,line cap=round,shorten >=0.2pt]
\tikzstyle{line2} = [line width=0.2pt]  
\tikzstyle{percent} = [font=\footnotesize]

%Piece 59,8%
\fill[piece1] (0,0) ++( 90 : 3 )coordinate(l1) arc (90:-90:3 )coordinate(r1)coordinate[pos=0.65](b2);
\fill[piece1] (r1) -- (0,0) -- (l1);

\fill[piece1] (0,0) ++( -90 : 3 )coordinate(l2) arc (-90:-125.28:3 )coordinate(r2) ;
\fill[piece1] (r2) -- (0,0) -- (l2);

%Piece 28,8%
\fill[piece2] (0,0) ++( -125.28 : 3 )coordinate(l3) arc (-125.28:-228.96:3 )coordinate(r3) coordinate[pos=0.5](b3);
\fill[piece2] (r3) -- (0,0) -- (l3);

%Piece 9,2%
\fill[piece3] (0,0) ++( -228.96 : 3 )coordinate(l4) arc (-228.96:-262.08:3 )coordinate(r4) coordinate[pos=0.5](b4);
\fill[piece3] (r4) -- (0,0) -- (l4);

%Piece 1,3%
\fill[piece4] (0,0) ++( -262.08 : 3 )coordinate(l5) arc (-262.08:-266.76:3 )coordinate(r5) coordinate[pos=0.5](b5);
\fill[piece4] (r5) -- (0,0) -- (l5);

%Piece 1%
\fill[piece5] (0,0) ++( -266.76 : 3 )coordinate(l6) arc (-266.76:-270:3 )coordinate(r6) coordinate[pos=0.5](b6);
\fill[piece5] (r6) -- (0,0) -- (l6);

%Pie Lines
\draw[line] (0,0) -- (r2);
\draw[line] (0,0) -- (r3);
\draw[line] (0,0) -- (r4);
\draw[line] (0,0) -- (r5);
\draw[line] (0,0) -- (r6);
\draw[line] (0,0) circle (3);

% Percentages
\path (0,0) -- coordinate[pos=0.65](b2m)(b2);
\node[percent] at (b2m) {59,8\%};

\path (0,0) -- coordinate[pos=0.65](b3m)(b3);
\node[percent] at (b3m) {28,8\%};

\path (0,0) -- coordinate[pos=0.65](b4m)(b4);
\node[percent] at (b4m) {9,2\%};

\draw[line2] (b5) -- ++(0,0.25) -- ++(-0.25,0.25) node[percent,anchor=south east]{1,3\%};

\draw[line2] (b6) -- ++(0,0.25) -- ++(0.25,0.25) node[percent,anchor=south west]{1\%};

%Legend
\node[piece3,draw=black,line width=0.2,rectangle,minimum width=0.25cm,minimum height=0.25cm,label={right:Fachholschulreife}](leg1) at (4,0) {};

\node[piece2,draw=black,line width=0.2,rectangle,minimum width=0.25cm,minimum height=0.25cm,label={right:Fachholschulreife},above=9pt of leg1.north] (leg2){};

\node[piece1,draw=black,line width=0.2,rectangle,minimum width=0.25cm,minimum height=0.25cm,label={right:Fachholschulreife},above=9pt of leg2.north] {};

\node[piece4,draw=black,line width=0.2,rectangle,minimum width=0.25cm,minimum height=0.25cm,label={right:Fachholschulreife},below=9pt of leg1.south] (leg4){};

\node[piece5,draw=black,line width=0.2,rectangle,minimum width=0.25cm,minimum height=0.25cm,label={right:Fachholschulreife},below=9pt of leg4.south] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't see any thin white line??? btw, have look here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/525376/pgf-pie-how-to-change-text-position-in-a-square-pie/525400#525400

Comment: @BlackMild There is a white line on some of the viewers (and at some magnifications). For instance, under Preview on a Mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to the question is that there is no need to draw these wedges in two stretches. For instance, instead of

```
\fill[piece1] (0,0) ++( 90 : 3 )coordinate(l1) arc (90:-90:3 )coordinate(r1)coordinate[pos=0.65](b2);
\fill[piece1] (r1) -- (0,0) -- (l1);
```

you can just use

```
\fill[piece1] (0,0) -- ++( 90:3)coordinate(l1) arc[start angle=90,end angle=-90,radius=3] 
coordinate(r1)coordinate[pos=0.65](b2)
-- cycle;
```

where `-- cycle` is not necessary but I find it cleaner. Please note that I switched to a more modern syntax for the `arc`s and `circle`, and replaced the deprecated `\tikzstyle` by the corresponding, nondeprecated `\tikzset` syntax (which are put in the options of the `tikzpicture`). Further simplifications are possible, and one may also use `pgf-pie` here.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[%Style Definitions
      piece1/.style={fill=black!5}, 
      piece2/.style={fill=black!20},
      piece3/.style={fill=black!35},
      piece4/.style={fill=black!50},
      piece5/.style={fill=black!65},
      line/.style={line width=0.4pt,line cap=round,shorten >=0.2pt},
      line2/.style={line width=0.2pt},  
      percent/.style={font=\footnotesize},
      box/.style={draw=black,line width=0.2,rectangle,minimum width=0.25cm,minimum height=0.25cm}]

%Piece 59,8%
\fill[piece1] (0,0) -- ++( 90:3)coordinate(l1) arc[start angle=90,end angle=-90,radius=3] 
coordinate(r1)coordinate[pos=0.65](b2)
-- cycle;

\fill[piece1] (0,0) -- ++ (-90:3) coordinate(l2) arc[start angle=-90,end angle=-125.28,radius=3]  
coordinate(r2) -- cycle;

%Piece 28,8%
\fill[piece2] (0,0) -- ++ ( -125.28:3) coordinate(l3) arc[start angle=-125.28,end angle=-228.96,radius=3] 
coordinate(r3) coordinate[pos=0.5](b3)
-- cycle;

%Piece 9,2%
\fill[piece3] (0,0) -- ++ ( -228.96:3) coordinate(l4) arc[start angle=-228.96,end angle=-262.08,radius=3] 
coordinate(r4) coordinate[pos=0.5](b4)-- cycle;

%Piece 1,3%
\fill[piece4] (0,0) -- ++ ( -262.08:3) coordinate(l5) arc[start angle=-262.08,end angle=-266.76,radius=3] 
coordinate(r5) coordinate[pos=0.5](b5)-- cycle;

%Piece 1%
\fill[piece5] (0,0) -- ++ ( -266.76:3) coordinate(l6) arc[start angle=-266.76,end angle=-270,radius=3] 
coordinate(r6) coordinate[pos=0.5](b6)-- cycle;

Pie Lines
\draw[line] (0,0) -- (r2);
\draw[line] (0,0) -- (r3);
\draw[line] (0,0) -- (r4);
\draw[line] (0,0) -- (r5);
\draw[line] (0,0) -- (r6);
\draw[line] (0,0) circle[radius=3];

% Percentages
\path (0,0) -- coordinate[pos=0.65](b2m)(b2);
\node[percent] at (b2m) {59,8\%};

\path (0,0) -- coordinate[pos=0.65](b3m)(b3);
\node[percent] at (b3m) {28,8\%};

\path (0,0) -- coordinate[pos=0.65](b4m)(b4);
\node[percent] at (b4m) {9,2\%};

\draw[line2] (b5) -- ++(0,0.25) -- ++(-0.25,0.25) node[percent,anchor=south east]{1,3\%};

\draw[line2] (b6) -- ++(0,0.25) -- ++(0.25,0.25) node[percent,anchor=south west]{1\%};

%Legend
\node[piece3,box,label={right:Fachholschulreife}](leg1) at (4,0) {};

\node[piece2,box,label={right:Fachholschulreife},above=9pt of leg1.north] (leg2){};

\node[piece1,box,label={right:Fachholschulreife},above=9pt of leg2.north] {};

\node[piece4,box,label={right:Fachholschulreife},below=9pt of leg1.south] (leg4){};

\node[piece5,box,label={right:Fachholschulreife},below=9pt of leg4.south] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! :) I droped use of `pgf-pie` since I saw no way to put percentages out of the pieces like in the custom made example above.