# Improve readability of Pie chart

Tags: tikz-pgf, shapes

I have a pie chart that displays percentage numbers in a crowded manner, and I want to improve its readability. Is there a way to do that? especially the way the 6.29% and 1.56% appears

[image]
The code is provided

```
\documentclass[sn-mathphys,Numbered,iicol]{sn-jnl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\input{Pie}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
[
    pie chart,
    slice type={comet}{blu},
    slice type={legno}{rosso},
    slice type={coltello}{giallo},
    slice type={sedia}{viola},
    slice type={caffe}{verde},
     slice type={C}{gray},
    pie values/.style={font={\small}},
    scale=2
]


    \pie[xshift=2.2cm,values of caffe/.style={pos=1.1}]%
        {}{38.57/comet,9.82/legno,37.79/sedia,5.88/C,6.29/caffe,1.56/coltello}
     

    
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{xxxx.}
\label{tabI}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

Inside Pie code

```
\usepackage{graphicx}%
\definecolor{rosso}{RGB}{220,57,18}
\definecolor{giallo}{RGB}{255,153,0}
\definecolor{blu}{RGB}{102,140,217}
\definecolor{verde}{RGB}{16,150,24}
\definecolor{viola}{RGB}{153,0,153}

\makeatletter

\tikzstyle{chart}=[
    legend label/.style={font={\scriptsize},anchor=west,align=left},
    legend box/.style={rectangle, draw, minimum size=5pt},
    axis/.style={black,semithick,->},
    axis label/.style={anchor=east,font={\tiny}},
]

\tikzstyle{bar chart}=[
    chart,
    bar width/.code={
        \pgfmathparse{##1/2}
        \global\let\bar@w\pgfmathresult
    },
    bar/.style={very thick, draw=white},
    bar label/.style={font={\bf\small},anchor=north},
    bar value/.style={font={\footnotesize}},
    bar width=.75,
]

\tikzstyle{pie chart}=[
    chart,
    slice/.style={line cap=round, line join=round, very thick,draw=white},
    pie title/.style={font={\bf}},
    slice type/.style 2 args={
        ##1/.style={fill=##2},
        values of ##1/.style={}
    }
]

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}


    \newcommand{\pie}[3][]{
        \begin{scope}[#1]
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\curA}{90}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{1}
        \def\c{(0,0)}
        \node[pie title] at (90:1.3) {#2};
        \foreach \v/\s in{#3}{
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\deltaA}{\v/100*360}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\nextA}{\curA + \deltaA}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\midA}{(\curA+\nextA)/2}
    
            \path[slice,\s] \c
                -- +(\curA:\r)
                arc (\curA:\nextA:\r)
                -- cycle;
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\d}{max((\deltaA * -(.5/50) + 1) , .5)}
    
            \begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground}
            \path \c -- node[pos=\d,pie values,values of \s]{$\v\%$} +(\midA:\r);
            \end{pgfonlayer}
    
            \global\let\curA\nextA
        }
        \end{scope}
    }
    
    \newcommand{\legend}[2][]{
        \begin{scope}[#1]
        \path
            \foreach \n/\s in {#2}
                {
                      ++(0,-10pt) node[\s,legend box] {} +(5pt,0) node[legend label] {\n}
                }
        ;
        \end{scope}
    }
```

Comment: Please never put Overleaf links and instead copy your code here and add a picture of what it produces, and maybe a description of what you want to be modified.

Comment: Pi charts and Pie charts are two different things …

Comment: Maybe [this Q&A](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/676342/47927) has some ideas for you

Comment: I found  several times people citing to     "*… the only worse design than a pie chart is several of them…*" attributed to  Edward Tufte, and it is not just a fallacy of authority. There are objetive arguments supporting this.  The best way to improve a pie chart ... is not use it. Use a bar chart instead.

Comment: You could use a [wheelchart](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82729)

Comment: @Fran Or just a simple table. [“Save the pies for dessert.”](https://www.perceptualedge.com/articles/visual_business_intelligence/save_the_pies_for_dessert.pdf) (PDF)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer below uses the [wheelchart](https://ctan.org/pkg/wheelchart) package, which I wrote.

A command `\WCtest` is defined of which the output depends on whether the percentage is larger than 7. This command is used in the keys `data` and `wheel data`. Here, the percentage is obtained with `\WCperc`.

The gap is obtained with the key `gap`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{wheelchart}
\definecolor{rosso}{RGB}{220,57,18}
\definecolor{giallo}{RGB}{255,153,0}
\definecolor{blu}{RGB}{102,140,217}
\definecolor{verde}{RGB}{16,150,24}
\definecolor{viola}{RGB}{153,0,153}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\WCtest#1#2{%
    \pgfmathparse{\WCpercentage>7?"#1":"#2"}%
    \pgfmathresult%
}
\wheelchart[
  counterclockwise,
  data=\WCtest{}{\WCperc},
  gap=0.02,
  perc precision=2,
  radius={0}{2.5},
  wheel data=\WCtest{\WCperc}{}
]{%
  38.59/blu/comet,
  9.84/rosso/legno,
  37.81/viola/sedia,
  5.89/gray/C,
  6.30/verde/caffe,
  1.57/giallo/coltello%
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```